# Django Redirects Causing Migration Error

Tags: django, postgresql, django-south

I recently updated my local database to mirror production and now I am having migration issues. Trying to migrate an application called events:

```
./manage.py migrate events
NoMigrations: Application '<module 'django.contrib.redirects' from '/Users/my_username/.virtualenvs/my_website/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/redirects/__init__.pyc'>' has no migrations.
```

I don't understand what is happening here. Why is it looking for migrations in the environment files? The migration has no problem running in production. Our site is running in Django 1.5.

Also, the `south_migrationhistory` table *does* have the `0001_initial` migration for redirects.

Comment: Still unsure what happened, but I copied the migration files from production and put them into the corresponding folders within my virtual environment as a band-aid fix.   ¯\_(ツ)_/¯